# Solving This Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this differential equation $${{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} - 2{{dy} \over {dx}} - 35y =  - (x + 3)$$

I think I need to try a polynomial of the form $ax + b$ but I can't make progress past that. If you could work through this example, I have a lot of others I can do on my own. Thanks for any help!

Comment: So why not try it? The lhs becomes $-2a-35(ax+b)=-35ax-(2a+35b)$. What values of $a,b$ do you need for that to be a solution? Having got a solution you then put $y=z+ax+b$ and find that $z$ satisfies a similar equation with 0 on the rhs. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I got to that but I didn't know how to solve for a and b. Why do you try with a z too? Surely there is only one constant because if there were two, you would just carry out the addition and get one constant. Right?

Comment: $a,b$ are just numbers, so you need the $x$ term and the constant term to agree, so $a=1/35, b=103/1225$. Now you put $y=z+x/35+103/1225$ and you find that $z''-2z'-35z=0$. Can you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is
$$
\lambda^2-2\lambda-35=(\lambda-7)(\lambda+5)=0
$$
and the the homogeneous solution is
$$
y_h(x)=c_1\mathrm e^{5x}+c_2\mathrm e^{-7x}
$$
A particular solution $y_p(x)=ax+b$ must satisfy $y_p''-2y_p'-35y_p=-x-3$
$$
-2a-35ax-35b=-x-3\quad\Longrightarrow a=\frac{1}{35},\quad b=\frac{103}{1225}
$$
and then
the general solution is
$$
y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)=c_1\mathrm e^{5x}+c_2\mathrm e^{-7x}+\frac{x}{35}+\frac{103}{1225}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{dy}{dx}$= a$$-2a-35(ax+b)=-35ax-(35b+2a)=-(x+3)$$Which implies that $35a=1$ and $35b+2a = 3$. Therefore y can be calculated from this.That clears the particular solution. The trivial solutions can be calculated from auxiliary equation of the homogeneous part of the differential equation.I hope this was helpful.

Comment: $−2a−35(ax+b)\neq −(35a+2)x−35b$

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that @alexjo.:)